# jquery position() not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, position

Has anybody else had problem with position() working odd in IE? I'm trying to return the left position of a div that is centrally placed. Chrome returns 342, which is right. IE9 returns 0.5. What's that all about?

```
  var sp = $('.jcarousel-container').position();
  alert(sp.left)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that .offset() does work in IE9 in your jsfiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fme6V/7/

Here's the code:

```
var sp = $('.jcarousel-container').offset();
alert(sp.left)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only workaraund I came to work out was to do something like:
var xpos_inside_parent = the_child.offset().left - the_parent.offset().left;
It worked for me, yet I hope it'll be fixed soon in jquery.

$('#whatever').position() works in IE9 if set by CSS by numer (e.g 'left: 20px;'), but this is trivial to me, because if I set position by CSS, then it's already known and there's no need to retrieve it by jquery.

The following example shows that it doesn't work with a 'margin: 0 auto' centered element. It also shows my provisional fix substracting offsets:
http://jsfiddle.net/maxoriola/MAwAH/4/

Comment: Thanks. This was awesome, and is relevant even in IE11. It is good to know that position() is relative in ie vs other browsers, but your work around is pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working using this code. Perhaps you can use it to correct your own.

http://jsfiddle.net/fme6V/

Comment: Ok. I might have missed some salient information. The div has a set size, a position which is relative and left and right margins set to auto, so it sits in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Could you post your code in jsfiddle? That way it'll be easier to take a look at it. ;)